# how to set parameter as an object in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

[Notes: all the code below use JavaScript with jQuery + jQuery-UI framework]

I mean, usually JS function parameters is just variable. So all we can do is set it like this:

```
function x(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, etc...) {/* code inside */}
```

But it doesn't like I could all use all of parameter that I've set. For example:

```
function flipCard(front, back, effect, option, duration) {
    $(front).click(function() {
        $(front).hide(effect, option, duration, function(){
            $(back).show(effect, option, duration)
        });
    });
}
```

You see, `option` is a very rare parameter that I could use. But the `duration` is alway used, I did consider a changing position of those parameters. However, it seem like I can do it forever so I think about using parameter as an object. I try many way I could think:

```
function t(obj = {x,y,z}) {/* code inside */} //Absolutely fail
```

Try again:

```
function t({}) {/* code inside */} //Ok, I give up
```

Do you have any idea to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are asking about....

In your flipcard you would have to check if the required stuff is passed though and if not output an error.

However, your code is not the best way to handle a situation...

```js
function flipCard(obj) {
    $(obj.front).click(function() {
        $(obj.front).hide(obj.effect, obj.option, obj.duration, function(){
            $(obj.back).show(obj.effect, obj.option, obj.duration)
        });
    });
}

//Call flipCard with an object
//obviously set your values as needed
flipCard({
  front : undefined,
  back : undefined,
  effect : undefined,
  option : undefined
  duration: undefined
});
```

Comment: I always love to hear a better suggestion code for my situation. Can please you show me? (A better code?)

Comment: I was referring to the binding of an click event inside of a function (unless you only call this function on load to bind to certain elements).

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of choices:

1. Use an "options" object:

   ```
   var xDefaults = {
       effect: "slide",
       option: "some default",
       duration: "slow"
   };
   function x(options) {
       options = $.extend({}, xDefaults, options);
       $(options.front).click(function() {
           $(options.front).hide(options.effect, /*... and so on... */);
       });
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   x({front: "#foo", effect: "fade"});
   ```

   Very clear; a bit clunky to use.
2. Detect when the function is called what kinds of options you have:

   ```
   function x(front, back, effect, option, duration) {
       if (/*...figure out that `option` is really `duration`...*/) {
           duration = option;
           option = null/*...or some default...*/;
       }
       $(front).click(function() {
           $(front).hide(effect, /*... and so on... */);
       });
   }
   ```

   It can be quite awkward to figure out which optional arguments have been supplied, but this is how jQuery does it for the majority of its functions. You can look at the types of the actual arguments you got, look at the magic `arguments` pseudo-array to know how *many* actual arguments you got, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure that I could understand the second choice. Could you make it be more clarified please? My English is not good enough to understand all the slang computer words like 'pseudo-array'.

Thank you for taking your time to help me :)